# Polynomials in $\Bbb Q[x]$ with same real root dont have common divisor with degree more than 1

Tags: ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f,g\in \Bbb Q[x]$ polynomyals with the same real root $\alpha \in \Bbb R$.
I'm asked wether or not $f$ and $g$ must have a common divisor $h\in \Bbb Q[x]$ with $\deg(h) \geq 1$.

I believe that the answer is yes, I just cant justify that.

Edit:
I think is solved that.
Let $I = \{p\in \Bbb Q[x] \mid p(\alpha)=0 \}$. Obviously $I$ is an Ideal of $\Bbb Q[x]$, and since $\Bbb Q$ is a field $\Bbb Q[x]$ is euclid Ring and therefore principal domain, so i'll just take the creator of I as a common divisor.

Comment: I suppose you mean $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @KajHansen: does it matter, since the case $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$ is trivial? (just take $h(x) = x- \alpha$)

Comment: It doesnt matter, if $\alpha \in \Bbb Q$ than im done ($x-\alpha | f,g$ in that case).

Comment: You are right.  I read the OP as $deg(h) > 1$.

Comment: Snufsan and @KajHansen : Do you see the difference between $deg(h)$ and $\deg(h)$ and between $Q[x] | p(\alpha)$ and $Q[x] \mid p(\alpha)$?  In each case, the second one is standard.  I edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4):

If a real (or complex) number $\alpha$ is the root of some non-zero polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then we say $\alpha$ is algebraic. Any algebraic number has a **minimal polynomial** $m_\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28field_theory%29)), which can be characterized in many ways:

- Out of the monic polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with $\alpha$ as a root, it is the one of least degree.
- Out of the monic polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with $\alpha$ as a root, it is the only one that is irreducible.
- Out of the polynomials that generate the kernel of the evaluation homomorphism
  $$\mathrm{ev}_\alpha:\mathbb{Q}[x]\to\mathbb{C},\quad \mathrm{ev}_\alpha(f)=f(\alpha)$$
  it is the monic one (note that $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a PID and the kernel is an ideal so the kernel can be generated by a single element.)

Note that since $m_\alpha$ is irreducible, it certainly has degree $\geq 1$.

Since we know that the given $\alpha$ is the root of some non-zero polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, it is algebraic, and has its minimal polynomial $m_\alpha$. Use any of the characterizations above to prove that $f$ and $g$ must both be multiples of $m_\alpha$. It would be useful to keep in mind that $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a Euclidean domain, i.e., it has a division algorithm ([statement EF1 on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Definition)).

Answer (score 3):

If $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$, then the problem is trivial since $(x-\alpha)$ will be a common divisor for all polynomials with $\alpha$ as a root.

Suppose $\alpha \not\in \mathbb{Q}$, then there is a  [minimal polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28field_theory%29) $h(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ with $\alpha$ as a root.  What we want to show is that, if there exists a $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ with $\alpha$ as a root, then $f(x) \in \langle h(x) \rangle$.

Well, consider the evaluation homomorphism $ev_\alpha:\mathbb{Q}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ defined as follows: $g(x) \mapsto g(\alpha)$.  If you haven't seen this before, you'll want to write up a quick proof that this is indeed a homomorphism.

The kernel of this homomorphism is an ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, which will be the set of all polynomials with $\alpha$ as a root.  Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, then $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a [principal ideal domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain).  That is, every ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is generated by a single element.  For completeness, you'll want to prove this fact as well.  Therefore, $\ker(ev_\alpha)$ must be generated by a single element.

Can you see why that element must be $h(x)$?  And why $f(x) \in \langle h(x) \rangle$?  From here, you can conclude that $h(x)$ will be a common divisor of all polynomials with $\alpha$ as a root.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the point of making $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}$ a separate case. The argument used for $\alpha\notin\mathbb{Q}$ applies just as well to rational numbers (rational numbers have minimal polynomials too, of course) and it seems good to me to emphasize that we can treat all algebraic numbers uniformly.

Comment: Ultimately, you are right.  The only reason I did it this way is because most people instantly recognize that the first case is true whereas the second case is a lot less obvious, and so structuring it like that perhaps appeals to a person's natural thought process.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(\alpha) = g(\alpha) = 0$, $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ is algebraic over $\Bbb Q$; thus there exists a polynomial $0 \ne m(x) \in \Bbb Q[x]$ with $\deg m(x)$ minimal among all polynomials $0 \ne p(x) \in \Bbb Q[x]$ such that $p(\alpha) = 0$; that is, if $p(\alpha) = 0$ then $\deg m(x) \le \deg p(x)$.  We can apply the division algorithm to $f(x)$ and $m(x)$, yielding $q_f(x), r_f(x) \in \Bbb Q[x]$ with

$f(x) = m(x)q_f(x) + r_f(x) \tag{1}$

and either $r_f(x) = 0$ or $\deg r_f(x) < \deg m(x)$; evaluating this equation at $\alpha$ yields

$0 = f(\alpha) = m(\alpha)q_f(\alpha) + r_f(\alpha) = r_f(\alpha), \tag{2}$

since $m(\alpha) = 0$.  But since $\deg r_f(x) < \deg m(x)$, if $r_f(x) \ne 0$ this contradicts the choice of $m(x)$ as having minimal degree.  Thus $r_f(x) = 0$ and hence $f(x) = m(x)q_f(x)$, so $m(x) \mid f(x)$.  Applying the same technique to $g(x), m(x)$ we have

$g(x) = m(x) q_g(x) + r_g(x) \tag{3}$

with either $r_g(x) = 0$ or $\deg r_g(x) < \deg m(x)$.  And again we see that this forces
$r_g(\alpha) = 0$ whence $r_g(x) = 0$ and $g(x) = m(x) q_g(x)$, so that $m(x) \mid g(x)$.  Note that since $m(\alpha) = 0$ we must have $\deg m(x) \ge 1$.

The question in the post may thus be answered in the affirmative:  $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have common divisor $m(x)$ with $\deg m(x) \ge 1$.

It should be noted that Snufsan's argument, edited into his question, is perilously close in spirit to mine; the key is to use the division algorithm on $m(x)$ and $f(x), g(x)$.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***